# What is wrong with my ESD discharge simulation circuit?

Tags: esd, ngspice

I am trying to duplicate the results given at the following URL in Qucs-s with ngspice.

https://www.youspice.com/simple-spice-esd-generator-circuit-based-on-iec61000-4-2-standard/

I must be doing something wrong because my initial current is about twice what is expected and curve is much flatter than expected (missing rebound).

Any advice appreciated.

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial conditions (.ic card) is effectively causing current to flow through R3 before the simulation begins. In the LTspice simulation below, a switch is used to delay the start of the important parts of the simulation. The switch closes 10ns after the start of the simulation which looks fairly similar to the web page you cited.

[image]